# Access from ejb from child jar to parent ear sources in maven project

Tags: java, maven, classloader, wildfly, getresource

I have a simple task, but can't make it correct.

I have one java maven project. This project builded in EAR, that consist of JARs and WARs. I have a bean in one of these child jars, which should get Resource from parent EAR from `META-INF/myFile.info`.

Unfortunately, i cant find correct way to do this. I'm deploying my EAR to **WildFly10**.

I am tryed to use ClassLoader, class, ContextClassLoader, tryed to define  in pom to add path to ClassPath.

What should i do to have ability get access from child jar java class(ejb) to parent ear sources from `META-INF/...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you-ear/META-INF/ is not visible from modules.
Only the your-ear/lib is visible from modules. If you want to share a EAR resource to all other modules, you should put you myFile.info in a jar in your-ear/lib

Comment: Thank you. I replaced config in accessible place.